# How to update the column of a table for different rows from another table's column through cursor in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to update the employee_id column of table employee_1 for top 151 rows  from employee_id column of employees table.But all the rows of employee_id column  of employee_1 table is getting up upated with only one row value of employee_id column of table employees.

The code used is:

```
    declare
        
            cursor c1 is select employee_id from employees;
            emp_id employees.employee_id%type;
        Begin
          open c1;
            loop 
              fetch c1 into emp_id;
              exit when(c1%rowcount>151);
              update employee_1 set employee_id=emp_id;
           end loop;
          close c1;
        end;

How to update the column with different values?
```

Comment: What do you think `c1%rowcount>151` is doing?  I'm also a bit lost on what you really want to do.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Because you have not used the `WHERE` condition:

```
update employee_1 set employee_id=emp_id; -- WHERE condition will be needed here
```

You need to use `WHERE` condition such that it identifies only single record from the `EMPLOYEE_1` table for each loop.

Comment: Adding to what @Tejash said. Because neither did you use *order by* on the cursor select you do not know you are getting the low 151 ids. Further without a limiting where clause you actually read the entire table. Have a look into the pseudo-column rownum.